# Zoom with UIScrollView and rotate with UIRotationGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiscrollview, cgaffinetransform

I'm trying to have an `UIImageView` rotate inside a `UIScrollView` but when I try to zoom/unzoom, **my rotation gets back to 0**.

Here's the code for my rotation :

```
- (void)rotateImage:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)rotate
  {
  if ([rotate state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
  {
    rotateAngle += [spin rotation];
    return;
  }

  myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakerotation(rotateAngle + [rotate rotation]);
}
```

Concerning the `UIScrollView`, I just return myView in `-(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:`

And a last information, in my interface builder, this is my view stack :

```
UIImageView
UIView (myView)
UISCrollView
```

Which means that I have a `UIView` between the `UIImageView` and the `UIScrollView`

Comment: Have you got a solution for this? I am stuck very much at the same point.

Answer (score 4):

I would rather suggest you to handle zoom using pinch gesture. It will look more neat and even . add pinch gesture to the view . for zooming add the following code in its selector method

```
   - (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{


   myView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recogniser.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
recognizer.scale = 1;

}
```

for rotating ,

```
    -(void)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rec
{


    myView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rec.view.transform, rec.rotation);
    rec.rotation = 0;
}
```

make sure you declare self as the delegate for both the gesture and implement the following delegate method

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

remove myView from

```
 -(UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:
```

method before implementing my solution. let just gesture alone handle the zooming and not scrollview.:) Good luck

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer, that's what was submited to another topic. But I've got several stuff linked to this ScrollView, so I was wondering if there would be a solution while keeping the ScrollView zoom.

Comment: well use CGAffineTransformRotate instead of CGAffineTransformMakerotation

Comment: Still have the same problem with CGAffineTransformRotate

Answer (score 3):

for pinch Gesture
 use the code from apple library

Don't forgot to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate`

```
self.ScrollView= [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
self.ScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, DEVICE_WIDTH, DEVICE_HEIGHT);
[self.view addSubview:self.ScrollView];

// for pinch Gesture
self.ScrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;
self.ScrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;
self.ScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
self.ScrollView.delegate = self;

[self.ScrollView addSubview:imageView];

-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{ 
    return imageView;
}
```

For rotation ,

```
UIRotationGestureRecognizer  *rotation = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRotate:)];
    rotation.delegate =self;
    [self.ScrollView addGestureRecognizer:rotation];

- (IBAction)handleRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;

}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```